# Laravel Share Session With Socket.io Nodejs

Tags: node.js, laravel, socket.io, session-cookies

My question is simple. How do I securely share laravel session information with my socket.io nodejs app. I've tried many different methods, none of them worked so I'm hoping a expert will pull through. I already know I don’t want to use JWT Tokens. So I guess that just leaves the session cookie data itself. I cannot figure out how to authenticate socket.io with the cookie so that’s what I need help with. I am storing sessions using redis, and using the default authentication system with laravel.

I’ve tried using this library which is great for parsing the session. But it does not authenticate with my socket.io server. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-laravel-session

If anyone knows how to fix this problem I would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have problem with authentication problem inside socket.io, idea is that you can't share the session from application to application easily, why? because this data is processed between the client's browser (cookie) and the server ( session ), if you want to connect Laravel and Socket.io, first you have to make some kind of flow like:

1. When user authenticates on website, to set cookie for socket.io as
   well (if host is different).
2. In background you have to share the session data trough database (memcached, redis etc), and with cookie. As you know, if you set laravel session param to work with database, instead of using files, laravel will automatically start saving session data into DB, so it's easy to read the session params from database.

I think you are using **node-laravel-session** by wrong, I mean if you have node.js application on other server and you use **getSessionFromFile**, it will not work. make sure you are using it correctly and it'll work. It's easy process itself to make thing like that, but mostly problem is security when you have cross-project sessions.